# No funciona setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'es_ES.utf8') en php

Tags: php7

Estoy intentando ordenar un array con la función sort de PHP. El problema es que no funciona bien con los caracteres acentuados y las eñes. Por ejemplo, si tengo el siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Manejo de arrays</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
             $listaPalabras = array ("Ñora", "Pedal", "Pedanía", "Juan", 
                                     "María", "Martini", "Mario", "Norberto", 
                                     "Begoña", "Begoniáceas", "Begoniáceos", "Begonias", 
                                     "Begonia");
            var_dump($listaPalabras);
            sort($listaPalabras, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
            var_dump($listaPalabras);
?>          

    </body>
</html>
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\DWES_REPE\CursoPildorasInformaticas\VIDEO_31\manejoDeArrays.php:17:
array (size=13)
  0 => string 'Ñora' (length=5)
  1 => string 'Pedal' (length=5)
  2 => string 'Pedanía' (length=8)
  3 => string 'Juan' (length=4)
  4 => string 'María' (length=6)
  5 => string 'Martini' (length=7)
  6 => string 'Mario' (length=5)
  7 => string 'Norberto' (length=8)
  8 => string 'Begoña' (length=7)
  9 => string 'Begoniáceas' (length=12)
  10 => string 'Begoniáceos' (length=12)
  11 => string 'Begonias' (length=8)
  12 => string 'Begonia' (length=7)

C:\xampp\htdocs\DWES_REPE\CursoPildorasInformaticas\VIDEO_31\manejoDeArrays.php:19:
array (size=13)
  0 => string 'Begonia' (length=7)
  1 => string 'Begonias' (length=8)
  2 => string 'Begoniáceas' (length=12)
  3 => string 'Begoniáceos' (length=12)
  4 => string 'Begoña' (length=7)
  5 => string 'Juan' (length=4)
  6 => string 'Mario' (length=5)
  7 => string 'Martini' (length=7)
  8 => string 'María' (length=6)
  9 => string 'Norberto' (length=8)
  10 => string 'Pedal' (length=5)
  11 => string 'Pedanía' (length=8)
  12 => string 'Ñora' (length=5)
```

Como se aprecia, Ñora debería ir delante de Pedal, y María delante de Mario. 
Lo del `setlocale`, que va entre comentarios, no funciona.

Estoy trabajando con la última versión de XAMPP (PHP 7).

Comment: Como aquí no aparece nada de mi código, intentaré abreviar: uso un simple "sort" de mi array de palabras, y los acentos y las eñes no se ordenan bien. He utlizado setlocale (LC_COLLATE, 'es_ES.utf8'), después sort($listaPalabras, SORT_LOCALE_STRING) y por último var_export($listaPalabras), pero sigue sin realizarse la ordenación

Comment: todo código que agregues dentro de una pregunta debes seleccionarlo y darle clic al ícono `{}` para que se vea completo y formateado, de todos modos ya te ayudé

Answer (score 0):

usa la clase Collator

```
$listaPalabras = array ("Ñora", "Pedal", "Pedanía", "Juan", 
                         "María", "Martini", "Mario", "Norberto", 
                         "Begoña", "Begoniáceas", "Begoniáceos", "Begonias", 
                         "Begonia");
$collator = new Collator('es_MX');// en_US, es_ES etc.
$collator->sort($listaPalabras);
print_r($listaPalabras);
```

Resultado

```
Array
(
    [0] => Begonia
    [1] => Begoniáceas
    [2] => Begoniáceos
    [3] => Begonias
    [4] => Begoña
    [5] => Juan
    [6] => María
    [7] => Mario
    [8] => Martini
    [9] => Norberto
    [10] => Ñora
    [11] => Pedal
    [12] => Pedanía
)
```

Si lo quieres en orden descendente

```
print_r(array_reverse($listaPalabras));
```